# scikit-learn RidgeCV scoring option not working

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I noticed that the `cv_values_` from RidgeCV is always in the same metric regardless of the `scoring` option. Here is an example:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

boston = load_boston()

mod = RidgeCV(store_cv_values = True, scoring = 'r2')
fit = mod.fit(boston.data, boston.target)
print(fit)
print(fit.cv_values_)

mod = RidgeCV(store_cv_values = True, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error')
fit = mod.fit(boston.data, boston.target)
print(fit)
print(fit.cv_values_)
```

The output is:

```
RidgeCV(alphas=(0.1, 1.0, 10.0), cv=None, fit_intercept=True, gcv_mode=None,
    normalize=False, scoring='r2', store_cv_values=True)
[[ 7.61705436  7.83092421  8.2298466 ]
 [ 2.50029583  2.31181064  2.11665248]
 [ 7.98280614  7.95286299  7.87166914]
 ..., 
 [ 5.24271689  5.50191347  5.84802692]
 [ 3.7448827   4.01778493  4.40457956]
 [ 0.0859419   0.37219929  0.89447484]]
RidgeCV(alphas=(0.1, 1.0, 10.0), cv=None, fit_intercept=True, gcv_mode=None,
    normalize=False, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
    store_cv_values=True)
[[ 7.61705436  7.83092421  8.2298466 ]
 [ 2.50029583  2.31181064  2.11665248]
 [ 7.98280614  7.95286299  7.87166914]
 ..., 
 [ 5.24271689  5.50191347  5.84802692]
 [ 3.7448827   4.01778493  4.40457956]
 [ 0.0859419   0.37219929  0.89447484]]
```

As you can see, the `cv_values_` are identical even though I specify different `scoring`. I would have expected the `cv_values_` to be in the `r2` metric in the first case. Am I missing something obvious? I am quite new to scikit-learn. This is scikit-learn 0.18.1 running on Python 3.5.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to RidgeCV.cv_values_ docs, from RidgeCV [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1144e3b513b632c1564f319416d23fdb99f2fd61/sklearn/linear_model/ridge.py#L1026) it looks like scorer is only used to choose best hyperparameters (set `self.alpha_` and `self.dual_coef_` attributes).

So either docs or source code should be changed to make behavior correct. Raising an issue in scikit-learn [bug tracker](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues) could be a good idea.

Comment: Do you know if this has this been fixed yet, as of February 2020?