# Significant mismatch between `r2_score` of `scikit-learn` and the R^2 calculation

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, goodness-of-fit

## Question

Why is there a significant difference between the [`r2_score` function in scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html#sklearn.metrics.r2_score) and the formula for the [Coefficient of Determination as described in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination)?  Which is the correct one?

## Context

I'm using  with Python 3.5 to predict linear and quadratic models, and one of the measures of goodness of fit that I'm trying out is the .  However, while testing, there's a marked difference between the `r2_score` metric in `scikit-learn` and the calculation provided in Wikipedia.

## Code

I'm providing my code here as reference, which computes the example in the Wikipedia page linked above.

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
import numpy

y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
f = [1.9, 3.7, 5.8, 8.0, 9.6]

# Convert to numpy array and ensure double precision to avoid single precision errors
observed = numpy.array(y, dtype=numpy.float64)
predicted = numpy.array(f, dtype=numpy.float64)

scipy_value = r2_score(observed, predicted)

>>> scipy_value:
```

As is evident, the `scipy` calculated value is `-3.8699999999999992`while the reference value in Wikipedia is `0.998`.

Thank you!

**UPDATE:** This is different from [this question about how R^2 is calculated in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23309073/1663942) as what I'm trying to understand and have clarified is the discrepancy between both results.  That question states that the formula used in scikit is the same as Wikipedia's which should not result in different values.

**UPDATE #2:** It turns out I made a mistake reading the Wikipedia article's example. Answers and comments below mention that the example I provide is for the linear, least squares fit of the (x, y) values in the example. For that, the answer in Wikipedia's article is correct. For that, the R^2 calue provided is 0.998. For the R^2 between both vectors, scikit's answer is also correct. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is the R2 value in Scikit learn calculated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309073/how-is-the-r2-value-in-scikit-learn-calculated)

Comment: I think the question you referred does not correctly answer my question.  There is no mention of the discrepancy between the results from both sources, and that is the main point my question tries to address.  In fact, whether the calculation in `scikit-learn` is valid or not is a *very* important point (and *why*) and in my opinion should be determined for future reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The referred question is correct -- if you work through the calculation for the residual sum of squares and the total sum of squares, you get the same value as sklearn:

```
In [85]: import numpy as np

In [86]: y = [1,2,3,4,5]

In [87]: f = [1.9, 3.7, 5.8, 8.0, 9.6]

In [88]: SSres = sum(map(lambda x: (x[0]-x[1])**2, zip(y, f)))

In [89]: SStot = sum([(x-np.mean(y))**2 for x in y])

In [90]: SSres, SStot
Out[90]: (48.699999999999996, 10.0)

In [91]: 1-(SSres/SStot)
Out[91]: -3.8699999999999992
```

The idea behind a negative value is that you'd have been closer to the actual values had you just predicted the mean each time (which would correspond to an r2 = 0).

Comment: So, basically, the result given in the Wikipedia answer is incorrect?

Comment: @JuanCarlosCoto no, wikipedia is correct. The wikipedia article states the `R^2` of a linear least-squares fit to the given `x-y` data is 0.998. The data given there is not `y` and `f`. See my answer for more.

Answer (score 13):

I think you have misinterpreted wikipedia. The example on wikipedia does ***not*** state:

```
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
f = [1.9, 3.7, 5.8, 8.0, 9.6]
R^2 = 0.998
```

Instead, it says that the `R^2` for a linear least-squares fit to the data:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1.9, 3.7, 5.8, 8.0, 9.6]
```

is equal to `0.998`

Consider this script, which first uses [`np.linalg.lstsq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) to find the least squares fit, and the uses both methods to find an `R^2` of 0.998 for both:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

x = np.arange(1, 6, 1)
y = np.array([1.9, 3.7, 5.8, 8.0, 9.6])

A = np.vstack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T

# Use numpy's least squares function
m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y)[0]

print(m, c)
# 1.97 -0.11

# Define the values of our least squares fit
f = m * x + c

print(f)
# [ 1.86  3.83  5.8   7.77  9.74]

# Calculate R^2 explicitly
yminusf2 = (y - f)**2
sserr = sum(yminusf2)
mean = float(sum(y)) / float(len(y))
yminusmean2 = (y - mean)**2
sstot = sum(yminusmean2)
R2 = 1. -(sserr / sstot)

print(R2)
# 0.99766066838

# Use scikit
print(r2_score(y,f))
# 0.99766066838

r2_score(y,f) == R2
# True
```

Answer (score 5):

Both method uses the same formula to calculate the R-Square. check out the code below:

```
    # Data
    X=np.array([1.9, 3.7, 5.8, 8.0, 9.6]).reshape(-1, 1)
    y=[1,2,3,4,5]

    # Import module
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

    reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)

    # Predict the target variable
    y_pred=reg.predict(X)

    # R-Square fitness
    print('R-Square(metrics):', r2_score(y, y_pred))


    # R-Square using score method
    print('R-Sqaure(Score):',reg.score(X, y))
```

Output:
R-Square(metrics): 0.9976606683804627
R-Sqaure(Score): 0.9976606683804627

Answer (score 4):

The coefficient of determination effectively compares the variance in the data to the variance in the residual. The residual is the difference between the predicted and observed value and its variance is the sum of squares of this difference.

If the prediction is perfect, the variance of the residual is zero. Hence, the coefficient of determination is one. If the prediction is not perfect some of the residuals are non-zero and the variance of the residuals is positive. Hence, the coefficient of determination is lower than one.

The toy problem obviously has a low coefficient of determination since most of the predicted values are way off. A coefficient of determination of `-3.86` means that the variance of the residual is `4.86` times as large as the variance in the observed values.

The `0.998` value comes from the coefficient of determination of linear least squares fit of the set of data. This means that the observed values are related to the predicted values by a linear relation (plus a constant) that minimizes the variance of the residual. The observed and predicted values from the toy problem are highly linear dependent and thus the coefficient of determination of the linear least squares fit is very close to one.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. The problem is that scikit learn uses the equation for R2 direct on the data.

y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

f = [1.9, 3.7, 5.8, 8.0, 9.6]

Scikit learn calculate SSR and SST considering y is True values and f is a prediction of the y.

Wikipedia uses y as a feature array (x) and f is who you need to predict (y). So there is a regression that became in f_pred = 1.97y + 0.11. So, now you have true values of f and f_pred of f. R2 is calculated between them.

y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

f = [1.9, 3.7, 5.8, 8.0, 9.6]

f_pred = [1.86, 3.83, 5.8, 7.77, 9.74]

if you use the equation (1- SSR/SST) using f and f_pred data:

SSR = SUM[(f-fp_pred)^2] = SUM[0.0016, 0.0169, 0.0529, 0.0196, 0.091] = 0.091

SST = SUM[(f-AVE(f))^2] = SUM[15.21, 4.41, 4.84, 14.44, 38.9] = 38.9

R2 = (1-0.091/38.9) = 0.998

Negative R2 in scikit learn means that your model is worse than the average of the observed train data. Negative R2 happens especially in test data because they do not participate in the fit modeling. When you have a negative R2 value in scikit learn, you are going to have an R2 close to zero using R2 of the linear regression between True and Pred values.